# Проблемы с Wi-fi и проводом на Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, сеть

Сейчас опишу порядок того, что я делал с самого начала.
Вначале я поставил винду, в ней создал подключение и там все поехало.

второй системой я поставил убунту, во время установки я воткнул вайфай приемщик(или как его там) и он увидел мою сеть вайфай и подключился, предложил подкачать обнову, я согласился и скачал ее, после окончания, предложило перезапустить пк, но после этого перестал работать вайфай, я отключил провод от роутера и воткнул в системник, так как такое пользование мне приоритетней.

но провод тоже не работал, я начпл гуглить и пробовал что то, что мне предлагали и это я опишу ниже.

1. ifconfig

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. dns - resolv.conf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. restart NetworkManager

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на этом идей нету больше, надеюсь на вашу помощь

Comment: Начать стоит с написания команды sudo ifconfig без опечаток.

Comment: @andreymal выдало тоже самое, что и на скрине

Comment: Он не может на существующую команду выдать, что она не найдена. Значит вы умудрились набрать два раза с опечаткой, попробуйте третий раз.

Comment: Ну и естественно не забудьте установить net-tools, если вы этого почему-то до сих пор не сделали.

Comment: Ifconfig не нужен, вместо него есть `ip a`

Comment: Выложи lspci и lsusb что покажут

Comment: @andreymal не нужен юзеру неттулс. Скорее фирмваре не установленно. На горячую после винды оно работает, а выключишь комп полностью и сломалось

Comment: К первому скрину sudo iwconfig